# Destroy jQuery autocomplete

Tags: jquery, ajax, user-interface, autocomplete

I'm using [Autocomplete jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) in one my project and I want to destroy autocomplete in one case.

I have a web page where there are 2 fields i.e `Country` and `Ext No`. Where user choose a country I'm triggering an ajax call to get all ext no for that country. If there are any ext no available for that country then I have set the autocomplete list on `Ext No` field. So where ext no is exist for a country then I'm able to set new autocomplete list on the `Ext No` field. But there are some countries which don't have any ext no, so in that case I want to destroy autocomplete list on `Ext No` field.

Below is the code I'm using to destroy autocomplete on `Ext No` field.

```
if ($('#ext_no').data('autocomplete')) {
  $('#ext_no').autocomplete("destroy");
}
```

But this is not working. I'm always getting `$('#ext_no').data('autocomplete')` as `undefined`. For the very first time it was undefined that's fine but when user choose a country for next time it should not return `undefined`.

Let me know if anyone has any idea what I'm doing wrong here or is there any other way to destroy autocomplete for field if it was set on that field.

Comment: jquery ui version used

Comment: Yes I'm using jQuery UI Autocomplete.

Comment: lol he wants to know which version of jQuery UI you're using. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in the newer versions of jQuery UI, the data property name is changed to `uiAutocomplete` not `autocomplete` So

```
if ($('#ext_no').data('uiAutocomplete')) {
  $('#ext_no').autocomplete("destroy");
}
```

- [Changed naming convention for .data() keys](https://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#changed-naming-convention-for-data-keys)

Comment: I'm still getting `undefined`!

Comment: I'm using it in a text field does that matter?

Answer (score 2):

for me worked this:

```
jQuery('#autocompleteid').on('blur', function()
    {
        jQuery(".autocomplete-suggestions").remove();
    });
```

this will remove all suggestions for `autocomplete` and will not provide `autocomplete` for that field.